# How to add overlay button for each video on the page that play() video on 'mouseover'?

Tags: javascript, function, nested-loops, onhover

**CONTEXT:**

- The page has multiple videos
- Each video on the page is previewed on mouseover *(done)*
- When mouseover on video, the overlay button appears for each video *(done)*
- When mouseover on overlay button, video preview continues to play (or restart) --> **can’t figure this one out**

I *GetElementsByClassName* , save into variable and then loop through all videos on the page and adding *EventListeners* with appropriate *play() / pause()* functions -> works just fine for *'mouseover'* video previews.

The moment I *'mouseover'* on the button, video stops and I get *"Uncaught TypeError: e.target.play is not a function at HTMLDivElement.videoPlay"* error in my console.

When I do a test in my console, I can play each video using the appropriate index in the following:
*buttons[0].nextElementSibling.play()*

But for some reason, I can't make it work in the function.

Any ideas on how to make it work?

HTML

```
    <div>
        <!-- Video segment -->
        <div class="vid-segment">
            <a class="vid-btn" href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> 
                <span>Add to cart</span>
            </a>
            <video class="video-preview" witdh="352" height="198" muted>
                <source src="static/videos/video1.mov" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <!-- Video segment end -->

        <!-- Video segment -->
        <div class="vid-segment">
            <a class="vid-btn" href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> 
                <span>Add to cart</span>
            </a>
            <video class="video-preview" witdh="352" height="198" muted>
                <source src="static/videos/video1.mov" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <!-- Video segment end -->
```

JavaScript

```
function videoPlay() {
    loop = true;
    play()
    console.log("Video plays")
}


function videoStop() {
    currentTime = 0;
    pause()
    console.log("Video stops")
}


const videos = document.getElementsByClassName('.vid-segment')
const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('.vid-btn')

for(var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++)   {
    videos[i].addEventListener('mouseover', videoPlay);
    videos[i].addEventListener('mouseout', videoStop);
    buttons[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        buttons[i].nextElementSibling.play()
    })  

}
```

Comment: Do you have a reason for using videoPlay & videoStop instead of adding the functionality the same way as "mouseover"?

Comment: @CaptainSquirrel For the readability and reusability reasons, I like to keep it separate. But yeah, in this case, it could have been called right away. I would likely do a code refactoring once I'd make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! The answer is as follows:

```
const videos = document.querySelectorAll('.video-preview')
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.vid-btn')

for (let i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    videos[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      console.log('play')
      videos[i].play()
    })
    videos[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
      console.log('pause')
      videos[i].pause()
      videos[i].currentTime = 0;
    })
    buttons[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        console.log('button hover')
        videos[i].play();
    })
    buttons[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        console.log('button hover')
        videos[i].pause()
        videos[i].currentTime = 0;
    })
  }
```